# Cannot run git fetch from Team City command line build step

Tags: git, teamcity-9.0

I have a simple command line build step in a Team City (9.0.2 build 32195) build configuration that just calls:

```
git fetch
```

but when I run the build configuration it just hangs. Running:

```
git log
```

works fine. Any ideas why `git fetch` hangs while `git log` works?

EDIT: The hanging issues seems to be caused by TC waiting for credentials when running `git fetch`. So the solution would be to somehow store the credentials for git for the user running the job.

[image]

Comment: Try a `git remote -v` to see if the remote is well set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see if a **[git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)** would alliviate the issue here: it would cache the password and allow for any git command requiring authentication to get the password that way.

See "[Managing Remotes / Caching your GitHub password in Git Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)" (since TeamCity server uses jgit, not git directly)

Noye that it is possible, as [noted in this thread](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5556781?tstart=0), that TeamCity does not support yet credential helpers.

> As a workaround you can clone repository via SSH and use default private key authentication method for example. In this case TeamCity will know nothing about your SSH key.
>   Or you can upload an SSH key into TeamCity and use it. In this case it is stored under TeamCity data dir, but not in the settings.